# How can I save Tumblr OAuth keys so the user does not have to authorize every session?

Tags: php, mysql, session, oauth

I have a function in my utility file that connects to the Tumblr API and is *supposed* to pull the OAuth data from the MySQL database, but I'm not sure how to do this, as it is not working. The main problem I'm having is trying to replace the `$_SESSION['t']` and `$_SESSION['s']` variables with tokens and secrets from the database.

**Utility file function (util.php):**

```
$consumerKey = 'XXX';
  $consumerSecret = 'XXX';
  $client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret);
  $requestHandler = $client->getRequestHandler();
  $requestHandler->setBaseUrl('https://www.tumblr.com/');

  function tumblrAuth($verifier) {
    global $client;
    global $requestHandler;
    global $user;
    global $con;
    global $consumerKey;
    global $consumerSecret;

    // use the stored tokens
    $client->setToken($_SESSION['t'], $_SESSION['s']);

    // to grab the access tokens
    $resp = $requestHandler->request('POST', 'oauth/access_token', array('oauth_verifier' => $verifier, 'oauth_token' =>));
    $out = $result = $resp->body;
    $data = array();
    parse_str($out, $data);

    // store our token and secret
    $token = $data['oauth_token'];
    $secret = $data['oauth_token_secret'];

      // we should probably put the token and secret in the database
      $s = "UPDATE user SET tumblr_token='$token', tumblr_secret='$secret', tumblr_verifier='$verifier' WHERE id='$user->id';";

      if($q = $con->query($s)) {
        // and prove we're in the money
        $client = new Tumblr\API\Client($consumerKey, $consumerSecret, $token, $secret);
        return $client;
      } else {
        // failed
        echo "Failed to update token and secret.";
        return false;
      }
  }
```

**Callback (tumblr_auth.php)**

```
require_once 'include/util.php';

  // If we are visiting the first time
  if (!isset($_GET['oauth_verifier'])) {

      // grab the oauth token
      $resp = $requestHandler->request('POST', 'oauth/request_token', array());
      $out = $result = $resp->body;
      $data = array();
      parse_str($out, $data);

      // tell the user where to go
      echo '<a href="https://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' . $data['oauth_token'].'"> GO </a>';
      $_SESSION['t']=$data['oauth_token'];
      $_SESSION['s']=$data['oauth_token_secret'];

  } else {
      if($tumblr = tumblrAuth($_GET['oauth_verifier'])) {
        header("Location:".$site_index);
      }
    }
```

I also tried using [this code.](https://github.com/tumblr/tumblr.php/wiki/Authentication)

How can I achieve this?